# I am not getting the starknet plugin from the plugin section

Tags: erc-20, contract-deployment

I am completely new and I want to deploy a contract on the eth network with my argent wallet. But I am surprisingly not getting ant starkenet plugin in the plugin menu. And no not even if I use other browser or the app itself

Comment: Do you want to deploy to some Starknet network or to some Ethereum network? They are different networks, and different technologies.